# Can anyone generate mongodb query for my scenario

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am new to MongoDB and using Mongoose to manage data to and from MongoDB. I have a collection having below structure:

```
var post= new Schema({
          message: String, 
          created_by_user_id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          created_at: Date,
          likes: [new Schema({liked_by_user_id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId})]
});
```

Below is the above collection with dummy documents:

```
[{
   "_id": "5c0254c13a22f222ceb861ad",
   "message": "from pppr",
   "created_by_user_id": "5c0253e9a53bed2165c0625c",
   "likes": [
     {
       "_id": "5c027a6fff5fcb5ab180e20c",
       "liked_by_user_id": "5c0253e9a53bed2165c0625c"
     },
     {
       "_id": "5c028e46abc09775c10d767b",
       "liked_by_user_id": "5c0234c1d8832b6af3b4f4a6"
     }
   ],
   "created_at": "2018-12-01T09:30:41.943Z",
   "__v": 0
},
{
   "_id": "5c0254c13a22f222ceb861ad",
   "message": "from pppr",
   "created_by_user_id": "5c0253e9a53bed2165c0625c",
   "likes": [
      {
         "_id": "5c027a6fff5fcb5ab180e20c",
         "liked_by_user_id": "5c0253e9a53bed2165c0625c"
      },
      {
         "_id": "5c028e46abc09775c10d767b",
          "liked_by_user_id": "5c0234c1d8832b6af3b4f4a6"
      }
    ],
   "created_at": "2018-12-01T09:30:41.943Z",
   "__v": 0
}]
```

Now, I am trying to get all documents along with status which will indicate that, whether I have liked the respective post or not. In request, I am also send my user id.

Basically, On my wall, system should show all the posts created by either me or by my friends along with extra status in each document which will show whether I liked the respective post or not.

I am saving user friends in separate collection named as "userfriends". The structure of this collection is given below:

```
var userfriends = new Schema({
      user_id_1: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      user_id_2: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      created_at: Date
});
```

I just want to get all posts along with that extra field. So, you can ignore the userfriends collection this is just for guiding you more.

Can any one help me on this? What will be the query which can fulfill my requirement?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`$addFields`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) along with the [**`$in`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) aggregation operator

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": { 
    "status": { "$in": [mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId), "$likes.liked_by_user_id"] }
  }}
])
```

It will add a new fields to your every post document with the boolean value

Comment: Can you help me on 1 more thing??

Comment: @Dhirender sure

Comment: I have 1 more collection. This contains messages between users along with is_read status with each message. collection contains columns like: user_from_id, user_to_id, message, is_read, created_at. Now I want list of friends sorted by recent messages along with count of un read messages. For reference, I want something like watsapp chat list like data.

Comment: I thought your question is related to the above answer. Ok no problem. Please ask a new question with some sample output and the expected output and with some pure explanation

Comment: Ok I will do now

Comment: Before posting new question, I have searched similar questions and found this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52722158/mongoose-get-last-message-each-conversation-in-mongodb This is exact what I want. Can you please look into there? Rather than saving user name, I am saving user ids

Comment: Ok great I have the answer. Even then  you have to ask a new question so that I can answer it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184909/discussion-between-dhirender-and-anthony-winzlet).